# Verificando valor em array e adicionar class css correspondente

Tags: php, mysql, query

Estou desenvolvendo um odontograma e no formulário cadastra qual dente ou dentes será feito o tratamento. É gravado essas escolhas em uma coluna e uma flag 0 em outra coluna relacionando que aquele tratamento dentário ainda não foi realizado. Ficando por exemplo:
 coluna dentes | coluna flag 
                13        0 
          17,18        0 
        11,15,21     1 
Se for zero o tratamento está em aberto, ainda não foi realizado e será inserido uma class para o dente ficar na cor vermelha, caso seja 1, sera inserido para aquele dente uma class verde, que o tratamento foi realizado e se não existir nenhum dente será adicionado class cinza. 
 O que não estou conseguindo é relacionar cada dente com sua flag e adicionar a class correspondente. Para cada dente no front no formulario será chamada essa função e irá verificar se aquele dente passado como parametro está registrado e marcará ele com a cor correspondente. Estou conseguindo encontrar  o dente, mas não estou conseguindo entender uma condição para ele adicionar a class corresponde se existir ou não o dente correspondente a sua flag. A variavel idPatient e teeth são passadas por parametro na função. 
 `

```
 $query = $this->db2->select( 'treatment_teeth, treatment_flag' )->from( 'tbl_enchiridion_treatment' )

 ->where( 'treatment_id_patient', $idPatient )->get()->result();

 $store = '';

  foreach( $query as $v )
  {
    $store .= $v->treatment_teeth . ',';
  }

  $substr = substr( $store, 0 , -1 );       

  if( in_array( $teeth, explode( ",", $substr ) ) )
  {
    return 'odontogram-tooth-on-process';

  }else{

    return '';
  }
```

}`

Comment: Coloque o HTML que o seu controller usa

Comment: @AndreiCoelho é muito HTML, posso coloca-lo no pastebin e postar o link aqui?

Comment: Não...  coloque apenas a parte que você quer alterar a classe do HTML. E se puder, insira o que você tentou fazer.

Comment: Vou postar somente então alguns blocos do html de 2 dentes, do 23 ao 24, mas lembrando que são todos os dentes, por isso disse que o codigo HTML é imenso. Mas eu chamo em cada bloco a função para verificar se aquele dente está cadastrado e em qual condição ele se encontra. Vou postar em outro comentário porque aqui vai exceder o tamanho, mas mesmo assim não vai dar o tamanho aqui, eu posso responder a minha pergunta colocando o código?

Comment: Não pode... =/ ... A resposta é só para resposta. Faz assim... Se ficou muito grande... Coloque a parte que você quer alterar, deixa claro isso... E coloque o código grande mesmo depois.... No final da pergunta, você escreve: Código html completo. Se não couber, coloque em algum link para download...

Comment: Esse é um bloco `<div class="odontogram-tooth-image-23 <?= $this->patient->checkTeeth($patient[0]->id_pt, 23); ?>"></div>
<div class="odontogram-number odontogram-number-23">23</div>` !Onde eu passo o id do client e o dente como parametros e para cada dente tem esses blocos com a mesma função para verificar o dente correspondente.